# Check a value is present in dataframe and get its index without using Column name

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I would like to check whether a value is present in dataframe and once found, get the index/position of it. Please note, I don't wish to use column names

Please find the sample input dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Person_id':[1,2,3,4,5],
 'Gender':[np.nan,np.nan,'1.Male','2.Female', np.nan],
           'Ethnicity':['1.Chinese','2.Indian','3.Malay',np.nan,np.nan]})
```

Here, I would like to check whether the number 3 is present in df. If present, get the index of 3

For which I tried below approaches/codes but didn't work,

```
 df.loc[df.isin([3])]
 df[df.isin([3])] - #THIS DOESN'T THROW ERROR BUT DOESN'T GIVE THE INDEX
 df.isin([3]).index - #doesn't help either
```

But it threw an error as shown below

```
  ValueError: Cannot index with multidimensional key
```

How can I get the index of element 3 in the dataframe? The expected value is 2, 1.

Please note that I don't wish to use column names, I want to run this search across the dataframe and get its location/position.

Comment: If you are looking for the number 3 then you need to specify the column. ```df.loc[df['Person_id'].isin([3])]```
Or otherwise you could try:
```df.loc[df.isin([3]).any(axis=1)]```

Comment: In real time, I may not know the column names, so can't I search across the df and get the index?

Comment: Do you also want to search strings containing '3' ?

Comment: No, I only want the position which is 2nd row and 1st column

Comment: Didn't downvote, but you may want to have a read through https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357436/why-isnt-providing-feedback-mandatory-on-downvotes-and-why-are-ideas-suggestin

Comment: Thank you.. I only know that it is downvoted, but don't know how can I prevent it/improve my question next time. Thank you for the link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want just rows which contain the number 3, and don't want to specify the name of the columns then:

```py
df.loc[df.isin([3]).any(axis=1)].index
```

or

```py
df.loc[(df == 3).any(axis=1)].index
```

Where the former is quicker in this example

```
%timeit df.loc[(df == 3).any(axis=1)].index
1.71 ms ± 40.5 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

%timeit df.loc[df.isin([3]).any(axis=1)].index
643 µs ± 3.31 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Comment: I am marking this as a solution, as this answer helped me a bit to accomplish my task. But I am not sure whether there is any other better way to get this done

Comment: If you are also wanted columns names, then you could try something like ```df.columns[df.isin([3]).any()]``` then you could extract the position of that using ```.get_loc``` as suggested by @Zaraki

Answer (score 1):

See this:

```
index = int(df[df['Person_id']==3].index[0]), df.columns.get_loc("Person_id")
```

Output:

```
(2, 0)
```

Comment: Is there anyway to find without using the column names?